# Disable logging for GKE autopilot

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

I am trying to turn off logging and monitoring for a GKE autopilot cluster, and I get error:

```
gcloud beta container clusters update my-cluster  --logging-service none --monitoring-service none

WARNING: The `--logging-service` flag is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release. Please use `--logging` instead. For more information, please read: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/installing.
WARNING: The `--monitoring-service` flag is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release. Please use `--monitoring` instead. For more information, please read: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/installing.
WARNING: Problem loading details of cluster to update:

ResponseError: code=404, message=Not found: projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-c/clusters/my-cluster.
Could not find [my-cluster] in [us-central1-c].
Did you mean [my-cluster] in [us-central1]?

You can still attempt updates to the cluster.

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.container.clusters.update) NOT_FOUND: Not found: projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-c/clusters/my-cluster.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Siegfred is right. There is no way you can turn cloud logging off for GCP Autopilot. GCP autopilot charges on its website is a big lie. Be ready to pay more than double of your estimated cost with autopilot manage service.

Cloud logging charges will be more than the charges of k8n autopilot cluster itself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34642978)

Comment: @David it is important information that GCP is lying about the costs of autopilot. Siegred's answer does not properly highlight that this is a big problem with GCP, while this answer focuses on the underlying problem that the user is facing, namely that the pricing is a lie.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the cluster is not found on the us-central1-c zone.
You need to make the command on the correct region with --region flag

However, the [--logging and --monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/installing#available-logs) flags are not supported by Autopilot Clusters.

Autopilot clusters must have logging enabled as the GCP Engineering Team needs all debugging information to help with any issues and the nodes are managed by GCP.

Comment: But this means I am paying for that service, right? So autopilot is cost more than Google states. Right?

Comment: Logs Pricing is constant and will only depend on the logs ingested on Cloud Logging, which also has a free [50GB per month](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#logging-pricing-summary)

You may follow the [GKE logs-best practices](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/finding-your-gke-logs) and Reduce your GKE log usage by adding logs [exclusions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#exclusions)

Comment: @SiegfredV. logging easily costs 5x what the cluster costs, and making this non-negotiable is a huge red flag.  This is a huge red flag with the GCP service as a whole.